# Appcelerator - Android: Registering module with name already in use

Tags: android, memory-leaks, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have an android module that specifies its name in its constructor:

```
super("mymodule");
```

It's because I need to get the module instance from another BroadcastReceiver Class.

I notice that when exiting (using back) the app and re-launching it, there is this warning:

```
TiApplication: (KrollRuntimeThread) [342,342] Registering module with name already in use.
```

It looks like Titanium doesn't release the module from the memory when the app exits. Is it a memory leak?

What happens when the app relaunches? Does it create another module instance? Or does it re-use the previous one?

Comment: FWIW - Android doesn't necessarily exit an app when you use the back button to back out. It simply backgrounds it and then foregrounds it when you re-launch it.

Comment: But the app does reset everything when you do that. Doesn't it? Well, would I have multiple module instances remaining in memory?